# How to know if package is compatible with current version of React? (Installing latest package versions without upgrading to React 18)

Tags: reactjs, npm, semantic-versioning, major-upgrade

I'd like to update the following packages in the project to new major releases without upgrading to the latest version of React:

- Zustand (3.7.1 -> 4.1.1)
- React Router (5.2.0 -> 6.3.0)
- Framer Motion (6.2.1 -> 7.3.2)
- Chakra UI (1.8.3 -> 2.3.2)

The app is built with React 17 (17.0.2).

How can I be sure that the most recent version of the package will work with React 17? Is searching package docs the only way? The official website of Chakra UI and Framer Motion says that the minimum version of React with new releases is 18. However, I didn't find any mentions on Zustand and React Router pages. In that case, updating Zustand and React Router to the latest version is safe, right?